# How can I scrape this particular jQuery site with python?

Tags: jquery, python, web-scraping

I want to scrape this site: `https://resultadoselecciones2016.onpe.gob.pe/PRP2V2016/Actas-por-Ubigeo.html`

They are using jQuery so the data isn't on the "normal" html code. I see this on the Chrome developer console:

[image]

[image]

So I did this on python 2.7:

```
import urllib
import urllib2

url = 'https://resultadoselecciones2016.onpe.gob.pe/PRP2V2016/Actas-por-Ubigeo.html'

data = "pid=844399127479680.2&_clase=mesas&_accion=displayMesas&ubigeo=140107&nroMesa=034915&tipoElec=10&page=1&pornumero=1"

req = urllib2.Request(url, data)
response = urllib2.urlopen(req)
print response.read()
```

But it doesn't work, it just print the normal html, not the response you see above.

How can I get this data?

Comment: You need a headless browser running on your server

Comment: You can use Selenium or RoboBrowser for such tasks.

Answer (score 0):

I just solved this. I used the `requests` module instead `urllib` and just copy/paste the entire header, like this:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url2 = "https://resultadoselecciones2016.onpe.gob.pe/PRP2V2016/ajax.php"
head = "[my entire header]"
data_get_departamentos = "pid=1037937475037058.5&_clase=ubigeo&_accion=getDepartamentos&dep_id=&tipoElec=&tipoC=acta&modElec=&ambito=E&pantalla="

r = requests.post(url2, data=data_get_departamentos, headers=head)
departamentos = r.text
```

Then I used `Beautifulsoup` to parse the html response. That's all.

Comment: Hi Kevin, what was your header for this?